Able to avoid minimum character limit in SG
Apparently you can avoid the minimum character limit of a post, in the Staging Ground, by editing a post and then using a different option, such as "require major changes". I was editing this post, which at the time contained the following content:

I Want to call a stored procedure with a csv file.
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
I am expecting results while running stored procedure.

I removed the spammed characters and "I expect..." text, which resulted in the question being only 50 characters long. Below the post I got the warning that the post was too short stating:

Body must be at least 220 characters; you entered 50.

I, however, had also commented that the OP needs to edit their post, to put details from the comments in the question, and continue to improve it, and then hit "Needs major changes". This allowed the edit to go through, making the entire content of the question:

I want to call a stored procedure with a csv file.

I suspect that I shouldn't have been able to submit that edit, while submitting the "needs major changes" review.

We can actually edit even without selecting any other review option than just "Save without review" (I just tried it out on the linked post). It's most likely not giving us the error as we can bypass that limitation due to having the edit privilege. This is the same behaviour we have outside of the SG as well when we have the edit privilege.

Now I wonder whether that would result in an "unknown error" while approving such a post - but I don't want to approve such posts

Why is this an issue? You cut out all the parts that don't belong, and presumably OP will have to flesh out the question should they make any changes.

The issue is that if I (other users) can bypass the character limit requirement, then we shouldn't be warned it's too short, @Laurel .

There have been meta posts recently which argue against having the minimum limit on edits, and now we have a meta post complaining it isn't there :) You can't win.

I'm, not against it not being there, @Gimby , but that I was informed the post was too short, but then could still submit it. As I stated, I suspect I shouldn't have been able to submit it, but if the desired behaviour is that I could, I shouldn't have been told it was too short. I was informed one thing by the error, but got different behaviour.
